# Identifying an IC named MT6617

Tags: power-supply, integrated-circuit, power-electronics

Can anyone help me how to identify the component in the following image ?
It's found on a power supply circuit (LED driver) 
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does that have 6 pins ?

Comment: Or 7 pins (8 pin DIP with one missing) in which case it may be equivalent to [FLS6617](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/FLS6617-D.pdf)

Comment: I've used MTxxxx led drivers, the company is [Maxic](http://www.maxictech.com/) but I can't find any with this code. They don't list all their ICs, some are documented as help ICs in the datasheet for other circuits.

Comment: @Overmind nope 8 pins DIP

Comment: @Finbarr yes, i'll look at this

Comment: @pipe it would helpful if you can redirect me to some references on how i can design my own Constant Current Powersupply ...